# how to build dockerfile when there is a class library in another folder

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, class-library, docker-build

I have a dotnet project and a class library project like this:

```
..solution-folder/
                app1/
                   - app1.csproj
                   - dockerfile
                   - other files
                app2/
                   - app2.csproj
                   - dockerfile
                   - other files
                app3/
                   - app3.csproj
                   - dockerfile
                   - other files
                core/
                   - core.csproj
                   - other files
```

And this is dockerfiles for each app:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS core-build
WORKDIR /src/app/core
COPY ["../core/core.csproj", "/"]
```

it gives error for copy command. it says:

```
   3 |     WORKDIR /src/app/core
   4 |
   5 | >>> COPY ["../core/core.csproj", "/"]
    ------------------------------------
   ERROR: "/core/core.csproj": `not found`
```

I understand that going to parent foler by (..) is not supported for the build context. Looks like I have to move dockerfiles to the solution-folder. But There are multiple dockerfiles. Should I combine them? if yes, how to generate 3 images for 3 different apps?

Answer (score 0):

The location you specify as the Docker "build context" is the root of all the stuff you have access to from within the build of the Dockerfile. All your `COPY` paths must be relative to that path and you can't go above it with `..`. So you need to set the build context directory so that you can access everything you need in the scope of that directory.

Comment: Hey @Matt Thalman, I updated the question based on your answer.